# Keras initializers outside Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I want to initialize a 4*11 matrix using glorot uniform in Keras, using following code:

```
import keras
keras.initializers.glorot_uniform((4,11))
```

I get this output :

```
<keras.initializers.VarianceScaling at 0x7f9666fc48d0>
```

How can I visualize the output? I have tried c[1] and got output `'VarianceScaling' object does not support indexing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `glorot_uniform()` creates a function, and later this function will be called with a shape. So you need:

```
# from keras.initializers import * #(tf 1.x)

from tensorflow.keras.initializers import *

unif = glorot_uniform() #this returns a 'function(shape)'
mat_as_tensor = unif((4,11)) #this returns a tensor - use this in keras models if needed   
mat_as_numpy = K.eval(mat) #this returns a numpy array (don't use in models)
print(mat_as_numpy)
```

Comment: yup getting output. How can i use this as numpy array

Comment: `K.eval()` is a numpy array. But if you're using this in a keras model, it's better to keep it as a tensor already.